# os.chdir() gives NoneType object

Tags: python, python-3.x, nonetype, python-os, chdir

I am changing my working directory to make sure images are loaded from the right place.

```
import os 
cwd = os.getwd()    ##works fine 
newwd = os.chdir("C:\\Users\\Me\\Python\\Images")     ##gives NoneType object
```

I never had problems with that before. 
Now as opposed to saving the variable as a string (i.e. the path I specified), it saves it as a NoneType of size = 1, so it is essentially empty. 
I tried with \, //, /, \, single or double quotations.
I copied even the line of code I used before, from a previous python file, and it still does the same.

Comment: [`os.chdir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.chdir) isn't documented as returning anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As described in the docs [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.chdir), `os.chdir(path)` changes the current working directory to the path specified. It doesn't return anything, hence why you get `newwd = None`. You can just run

```
os.chdir("C:\\Users\\Me\\Python\\Images")
```

to change the working directory. Then `os.getcwd()` will return `"C:\\Users\\Me\\Python\\Images"`.